# Is $\varphi:\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}\to X=\mathcal{V}(y^2-x^3-x^2)\subset \mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{C}, \varphi(t)=(t^2-1,t^3-t)$ the normalization of $X$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

There is a proposition in Attiyah's "Introduction to Commutative Algebra" which proves that $\exists ! \tilde{X}$ an affine normal variety and $\exists \phi: \tilde{X} \to X$ a finite morfism such that given another affine normal variety $Y$ and a dominant morfism $\psi: Y \to X$, then it exists an unique morfism $\tilde{\psi}:Y \to \tilde{X}$ that satisfies $\psi = \phi\ \circ\ \tilde{\psi}$. $\tilde{X}$ is called the normalization of X.

With that definition of normalization I have tried to prove that $\varphi$ is the normalization of X, both defined in the statement. I think that if I can prove $\overline{\mathcal{A}(X)}^{\mathcal{K}(X)}\cong \mathbb{C}[t]$ then it is finished but I am stuck and I do not know where to follow.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: $X$ is generically smooth since the gradient of $y^2-x^3-x^2$ does not vanish everywhere on $X$. So the normalisation $X'$ of $X$ is birational over $X$. The morphism $\phi$ is also birational since it has the rational inverse $(x,y)\mapsto y/x$. Hence, by Atiyah's result, you get a birational map ${\bf A}^1_{\bf C}\to X'$. The map $\phi$ is finite since $t$ statisfies the integral equation $t^2-1-x$ over the coordinate ring of $X$. Hence the birational map ${\bf A}^1_{\bf C}\to X'$ is also finite and so it must be an isomorphism by Zariski's main theorem.